# Switch statement and String to byte

Tags: java, class, byte, switch-statement

`byte color` have to keep colors (like red or green).
Result of `show()` method have to use switch to classify and describe this colors (in different variants like: red-blue, green-red etc.) *can't use enum

```
public class Candy {

    //fields
    int quantity;
    byte color;
    double price;

    //constructor
    Candy(int quantity, byte color, double price)
    {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.color = color;
        this.price = price;
    }

    //this method have to show class fields
        public void show(String colors) 
    {
        switch(color)
        {
        case 1: colors = "red";
        case 2: colors = "green";
        case 3: colors = "blue";
    }

            //tried to convert 
    //String red = "Red";
    //byte[] red1 = red.getBytes();
    //String green = "Green";
    //byte[] green1 =  green.getBytes();



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    //program   
    }
}
```

Am I on good way? How to keep Strings in byte? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean encoding all possible combinations of these three colors in one byte?

Comment: @bellum Every single bit of that byte(color) have to store one color.

Comment: @Code-Guru I don't know how to store this colors in byte :/

Comment: The way you are doing it certainly works if you only want three colors. Of course, you can have up to 256 colors with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one `byte` you can store 8 possible combinations.
In my decision I stated that first position (in binary representation of byte) is "blue" color, second - "green" and third - "red". This means if we have `001` - it's blue color. If `101` - its red-blue color and so on.
This is your `show()` method:

```
public void show() 
{
    switch (color & 4){
        case 4:
            System.out.print("red ");
        default:
            switch (color & 2){
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("green ");
                default:
                    switch (color & 1){
                        case 1:
                            System.out.print("blue");
                    }
            }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Calling of method:

```
new Candy(1, (byte)7, 10d).show(); //prints "red green blue"
```

Comment: There is necessary to use switch statement :/ Is there any way to do this without using StringBuilder? Anyway thanks !

Answer (score 3):

A switch is not a good choice, because you need a `break` in every case, which makes for a lot a code to do very little:

```
switch (color) {
   case 1: colors = "red"; break;
   ... etc
```

Also, having so many lines means there is more scope for bugs.
But worse, you are essentially using code to store data.

A better choice is to use a Map and look up the String:

```
private static Map<Byte, String> map = new HashMap<Byte, String>() {{
    put(1, "red");
    put(2, "green");
    etc
}};
```

then in your method simply

```
return map.get(color);
```